# Traefik persistant volume timeouts AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, lets-encrypt, kubernetes-helm, traefik

Im struggling to get Traefik working on K8s with ACME enabled. I want to store the certs as suggested on a persistantVolume. This for the fact that requesting certs is rateLimited and in case of pod restarts the cert would get lost. Below is my full config that is used for stable/traefik (helm chart) and installed in Azure AKS.

There are a issue that do not seem to work (or im just doing it wrong ofcourse).

**pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims**

This is the initial error that i receive when booting up the pods. The weird thing is that the PersistantVolumeClaim is actually there and ready. When i change the volume itself in my Azure portal it also says its mount to my server

```
traefik-acme
Namespace: default
pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-disk
Creation Time: 2019-04-16T09:55 UTC
Status: Bound
Volume: pvc-b673da74-602d-11e9-a537-9275388
Access modes: ReadWriteOnce
Storage class: default
```

Also the storageClass itself is active:

```
$ kubectl get sc --all-namespaces
NAME                PROVISIONER                AGE
default (default)   kubernetes.io/azure-disk   4d
managed-premium     kubernetes.io/azure-disk   4d
```

When i then wait a little longer i receive below error:
`Unable to mount volumes for pod "traefik-d65fcbc8b-lkzsh_default(b68c8aa3-602d-11e9-a537-92753888c74b)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "default"/"traefik-d65fcbc8b-lkzsh". list of unmounted volumes=[acme]. list of unattached volumes=[config acme default-token-p2lgf]`

Here the full K8s event trace:

```
pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
default-scheduler
2019-04-16T09:55 UTC

Successfully assigned default/traefik-d65fcbc8b-lkzsh to aks-default-22301976-0
default-scheduler
2019-04-16T09:55 UTC

Unable to mount volumes for pod "traefik-d65fcbc8b-lkzsh_default(b68c8aa3-602d-11e9-a537-92753888c74b)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach or mount for pod "default"/"traefik-d65fcbc8b-lkzsh". list of unmounted volumes=[acme]. list of unattached volumes=[config acme default-token-p2lgf]
kubelet aks-default-22301976-0
2019-04-16T09:57 UTC

AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-b673da74-602d-11e9-a537-92753888c74b"
attachdetach-controller
2019-04-16T09:58 UTC

Container image "traefik:1.7.9" already present on machine
kubelet aks-default-22301976-0
2019-04-16T10:01 UTC

Created container
kubelet aks-default-22301976-0
2019-04-16T10:00 UTC

Started container
kubelet aks-default-22301976-0
2019-04-16T10:00 UTC

Back-off restarting failed container
kubelet aks-default-22301976-0
2019-04-16T10:02 UTC
```

### Install

Installing the helm chart of Traefik done with:

`helm install -f values.yaml stable/traefik --name traefik`

Below is the full `values.yaml` used to install the chart

```
## Default values for Traefik
image: traefik
imageTag: 1.7.9

testFramework:
  image: "dduportal/bats"
  tag: "0.4.0"

## can switch the service type to NodePort if required
serviceType: LoadBalancer
# loadBalancerIP: ""
# loadBalancerSourceRanges: []
whiteListSourceRange: []
externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
replicas: 1
# startupArguments:
#   - "--ping"
#   - "--ping.entrypoint=http"

podDisruptionBudget: {}
  # maxUnavailable: 1
  # minAvailable: 2

# priorityClassName: ""

# rootCAs: []

resources: {}

debug:
  enabled: false

deploymentStrategy: {}
  # rollingUpdate:
  #   maxSurge: 1
  #   maxUnavailable: 0
  # type: RollingUpdate

securityContext: {}
env: {}

nodeSelector: {}
  # key: value
affinity: {}
  # key: value
tolerations: []
# - key: "key"
#   operator: "Equal|Exists"
#   value: "value"
#   effect: "NoSchedule|PreferNoSchedule|NoExecute(1.6 only)"
## Kubernetes ingress filters
# kubernetes:
  # endpoint:
  # namespaces:
  # - default
  # labelSelector:
  # ingressClass:
  # ingressEndpoint:
  #   hostname: "localhost"
  #   ip: "127.0.0.1"
  #   publishedService: "namespace/servicename"
  #   useDefaultPublishedService: false
proxyProtocol:
  enabled: false
  # trustedIPs is required when enabled
  trustedIPs: []
  # - 10.0.0.0/8
forwardedHeaders:
  enabled: false
  # trustedIPs is required when enabled
  trustedIPs: []
  # - 10.0.0.0/8

## Add arbitrary ConfigMaps to deployment
## Will be mounted to /configs/, i.e. myconfig.json would
## be mounted to /configs/myconfig.json.
configFiles: {}
  # myconfig.json: |
  #   filecontents...

## Add arbitrary Secrets to deployment
## Will be mounted to /secrets/, i.e. file.name would
## be mounted to /secrets/mysecret.txt.
## The contents will be base64 encoded when added
secretFiles: {}
  # mysecret.txt: |
  #   filecontents...

ssl:
  enabled: false
  enforced: false
  permanentRedirect: false
  upstream: false
  insecureSkipVerify: false
  generateTLS: false
  # defaultCN: "example.com"
    # or *.example.com
  defaultSANList: []
    # - example.com
    # - test1.example.com
  defaultIPList: []
    # - 1.2.3.4
  # cipherSuites: []
  # https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/entrypoints/#specify-minimum-tls-version
  # tlsMinVersion: VersionTLS12
  defaultCert: 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
  defaultKey: 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
  # Basic auth to protect all the routes. Can use htpasswd to generate passwords
  # > htpasswd -n -b testuser testpass
  # > testuser:$apr1$JXRA7j2s$LpVns9vsme8FHN0r.aSt11
  auth: {}
    # basic:
    #   testuser: $apr1$JXRA7j2s$LpVns9vsme8FHN0r.aSt11

kvprovider:
  ## If you want to run Traefik in HA mode, you will need to setup a KV Provider. Therefore you can choose one of
  ## * etcd
  ## * consul
  ## * boltdb
  ## * zookeeper
  ##
  ## ref: https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/cluster/

  ## storeAcme has to be enabled to support HA Support using acme, but at least one kvprovider is needed
  storeAcme: false
  importAcme: false

  # etcd:
    # endpoint: etcd-service:2379
    # useAPIV3: false
    # watch: true
    # prefix: traefik

    ## Override default configuration template.
    ## For advanced users :)
    ##
    ## Optional
    # filename: consul.tmpl
    # username: foo
    # password: bar
    # tls:
    #   ca: "/etc/ssl/ca.crt"
    #   cert: "/etc/ssl/consul.crt"
    #   key: "/etc/ssl/consul.key"
    #   insecureSkipVerify: true
    #
  # consul:
    # endpoint: consul-service:8500
    # watch: true
    # prefix: traefik

    ## Override default configuration template.
    ## For advanced users :)
    ##
    ## Optional
    # filename: consul.tmpl
    # username: foo
    # password: bar
    # tls:
    #   ca: "/etc/ssl/ca.crt"
    #   cert: "/etc/ssl/consul.crt"
    #   key: "/etc/ssl/consul.key"
    #   insecureSkipVerify: true

    ## only relevant for etcd

acme:
  enabled: true
  email: me@gmail.com
  onHostRule: true
  staging: true
  logging: true
  # Configure a Let's Encrypt certificate to be managed by default.
  # This is the only way to request wildcard certificates (works only with dns challenge).
  domains:
    enabled: true
    # List of sets of main and (optional) SANs to generate for
    # for wildcard certificates see https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/#wildcard-domains
    domainsList:
      - main: "*.k8s-test.hardstyletop40.com"
      # - sans:
        # - "k8s-test.hardstyletop40.com"
      # - main: "*.example2.com"
      # - sans:
      #   - "test1.example2.com"
      #   - "test2.example2.com"
  ## ACME challenge type: "tls-sni-01", "tls-alpn-01", "http-01" or "dns-01"
  ## Note the chart's default of tls-sni-01 has been DEPRECATED and (except in
  ## certain circumstances) DISABLED by Let's Encrypt. It remains as a default
  ## value in this chart to preserve legacy behavior and avoid a breaking
  ## change. Users of this chart should strongly consider making the switch to
  ## the recommended "tls-alpn-01" (avaialbe since v1.7), dns-01 or http-01
  ## (available since v1.5) challenge.
  challengeType: tls-alpn-01
  ## Configure dnsProvider to perform domain verification using dns challenge
  ## Applicable only if using the dns-01 challenge type
  delayBeforeCheck: 0
  resolvers: []
    # - 1.1.1.1:53
    # - 8.8.8.8:53
  dnsProvider:
    name: nil
    auroradns:
      AURORA_USER_ID: ""
      AURORA_KEY: ""
      AURORA_ENDPOINT: ""
    azure:
      AZURE_CLIENT_ID: ""
      AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET: ""
      AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ""
      AZURE_TENANT_ID: ""
      AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: ""
    cloudflare:
      CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL: ""
      CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY: ""
    digitalocean:
      DO_AUTH_TOKEN: ""
    dnsimple:
      DNSIMPLE_OAUTH_TOKEN: ""
      DNSIMPLE_BASE_URL: ""
    dnsmadeeasy:
      DNSMADEEASY_API_KEY: ""
      DNSMADEEASY_API_SECRET: ""
      DNSMADEEASY_SANDBOX: ""
    dnspod:
      DNSPOD_API_KEY: ""
    dyn:
      DYN_CUSTOMER_NAME: ""
      DYN_USER_NAME: ""
      DYN_PASSWORD: ""
    exoscale:
      EXOSCALE_API_KEY: ""
      EXOSCALE_API_SECRET: ""
      EXOSCALE_ENDPOINT: ""
    gandi:
      GANDI_API_KEY: ""
    godaddy:
      GODADDY_API_KEY: ""
      GODADDY_API_SECRET: ""
    gcloud:
      GCE_PROJECT: ""
      GCE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE: ""
    linode:
      LINODE_API_KEY: ""
    namecheap:
      NAMECHEAP_API_USER: ""
      NAMECHEAP_API_KEY: ""
    ns1:
      NS1_API_KEY: ""
    otc:
      OTC_DOMAIN_NAME: ""
      OTC_USER_NAME: ""
      OTC_PASSWORD: ""
      OTC_PROJECT_NAME: ""
      OTC_IDENTITY_ENDPOINT: ""
    ovh:
      OVH_ENDPOINT: ""
      OVH_APPLICATION_KEY: ""
      OVH_APPLICATION_SECRET: ""
      OVH_CONSUMER_KEY: ""
    pdns:
      PDNS_API_URL: ""
    rackspace:
      RACKSPACE_USER: ""
      RACKSPACE_API_KEY: ""
    rfc2136:
      RFC2136_NAMESERVER: ""
      RFC2136_TSIG_ALGORITHM: ""
      RFC2136_TSIG_KEY: ""
      RFC2136_TSIG_SECRET: ""
      RFC2136_TIMEOUT: ""
    route53:
      AWS_REGION: ""
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ""
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ""
    vultr:
      VULTR_API_KEY: ""
  ## Save ACME certs to a persistent volume.
  ## WARNING: If you do not do this and you did not have configured
  ## a kvprovider, you will re-request certs every time a pod (re-)starts
  ## and you WILL be rate limited!
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    annotations: {}
    ## acme data Persistent Volume Storage Class
    ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
    ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
    ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
    ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
    ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
    ##
    storageClass: "default"
    accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
    size: 1Gi
    ## A manually managed Persistent Volume Claim
    ## Requires persistence.enabled: true
    ## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
    ##
    # existingClaim:
dashboard:
  enabled: true
  domain: traefik.k8s-test.hardstyletop40.com
  # serviceType: ClusterIP
  service: {}
    # annotations:
    #   key: value
  ingress: {}
    # annotations:
    #   key: value
    # labels:
    #   key: value
    # tls:
      # - hosts:
      #   - traefik.example.com
      #   secretName: traefik-default-cert
  auth: {}
    # basic:
    #   username: password
  statistics: {}
    ## Number of recent errors to show in the ‘Health’ tab
    # recentErrors:
service:
  # annotations:
  #   key: value
  # labels:
  #   key: value
  ## Further config for service of type NodePort
  ## Default config with empty string "" will assign a dynamic
  ## nodePort to http and https ports
  nodePorts:
    http: ""
    https: ""
  ## If static nodePort configuration is required it can be enabled as below
  ## Configure ports in allowable range (eg. 30000 - 32767 on minikube)
  # nodePorts:
  #   http: 30080
  #   https: 30443
gzip:
  enabled: true
traefikLogFormat: json
accessLogs:
  enabled: false
  ## Path to the access logs file. If not provided, Traefik defaults it to stdout.
  # filePath: ""
  format: common  # choices are: common, json
  ## for JSON logging, finer-grained control over what is logged. Fields can be
  ## retained or dropped, and request headers can be retained, dropped or redacted
  fields:
    # choices are keep, drop
    defaultMode: keep
    names: {}
      # ClientUsername: drop
    headers:
      # choices are keep, drop, redact
      defaultMode: keep
      names: {}
        # Authorization: redact
rbac:
  enabled: false
## Enable the /metrics endpoint, for now only supports prometheus
## set to true to enable metric collection by prometheus
metrics:
  prometheus:
    enabled: false
    ## If true, prevents exposing port 8080 on the main Traefik service, reserving
    ## it to the dashboard service only
    restrictAccess: false
    # buckets: [0.1,0.3,1.2,5]
  datadog:
    enabled: false
    # address: localhost:8125
    # pushinterval: 10s
  statsd:
    enabled: false
    # address: localhost:8125
    # pushinterval: 10s
deployment:
  # labels to add to the pod container metadata
  # podLabels:
  #   key: value
  # podAnnotations:
  #   key: value
  hostPort:
    httpEnabled: false
    httpsEnabled: false
    dashboardEnabled: false
    # httpPort: 80
    # httpsPort: 443
    # dashboardPort: 8080
sendAnonymousUsage: false
tracing:
  enabled: false
  serviceName: traefik
  # backend: choices are jaeger, zipkin, datadog
  # jaeger:
  #   localAgentHostPort: "127.0.0.1:6831"
  #   samplingServerURL: http://localhost:5778/sampling
  #   samplingType: const
  #   samplingParam: 1.0
  # zipkin:
  #   httpEndpoint: http://localhost:9411/api/v1/spans
  #   debug: false
  #   sameSpan: false
  #   id128bit: true
  # datadog:
  #   localAgentHostPort: "127.0.0.1:8126"
  #   debug: false
  #   globalTag: ""

## Create HorizontalPodAutoscaler object.
##
# autoscaling:
#   minReplicas: 1
#   maxReplicas: 10
#   metrics:
#   - type: Resource
#     resource:
#       name: cpu
#       targetAverageUtilization: 60
#   - type: Resource
#     resource:
#       name: memory
#       targetAverageUtilization: 60

## Timeouts
##
# timeouts:
#   ## responding are timeouts for incoming requests to the Traefik instance
#   responding:
#     readTimeout: 0s
#     writeTimeout: 0s
#     idleTimeout: 180s
#   ## forwarding are timeouts for requests forwarded to the backend servers
#   forwarding:
#     dialTimeout: 30s
#     responseHeaderTimeout: 0s
```

Comment: In AWS this would have to do with security groups on the cluster and the permissions to see the disk. Maybe something is off with your permissions? How are you generating these certificates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that attaching external Azure resources is slow on which initially a retry is there. There the pod gives a lot of errors that it can not mount since the volume is dynamicly created. Due the retry jt recover after a few minutes.

In fact the actual container crash was due an issue with ACME and Traefik itself and not directly with the volumes.

Answer (score 3):

For your issue, it seems you misunderstand the persist volume claims. When you use the command:

```
kubectl get sc --all-namespaces
```

It just shows the storage class, not the persist volume claims. The storage class is used to define how a unit of storage is dynamically created with a persistent volume. You need to create the persist volume claims as you need like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: azure-managed-disk
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: managed-premium
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

And you can use the command to show the persist volume claims like below:

```
kubectl get pvc --all-namespaces
```

And it actually shows the persist volume claims that you create. Take a look at the [Dynamically create and use a persistent volume with Azure disks in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disks-dynamic-pv). Or [Use the special disk that you create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disk-volume).

**Update**

Also, I get the error as you, but when the pod in the running state, I check inside the pod and find the volumes all mounted correctly. So I guess if the error came because the pod is not in the running state. When the pod in the running state, volumes will mount as expected.

Comment: Well the persistant volume is there and create by the helm chart itself: 

NAMESPACE    NAME                          STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
default      traefik-acme                  Bound    pvc-b673da74-602d-11e9-a537-92753888c74b   1Gi        RWO            default        22h

Comment: @Dirkos You can check the volumes inside the pod if the volumes mount or not. I also get the error but I find the volumes already mounted in the pod.

Comment: i cant access the POD since it crashes?

Comment: @Dirkos Any other errors? just cannot attach the volumes?

Comment: Seems there is just a big delay in the auto provision of the volumes. It is handled now and the actual crashed is caused by something else

Comment: It was not the actual answer since the problem was also a bit vague from my end. I upvoted your answer though since it is useful information for other members

Comment: @Dirkos Well, anyone cannot give you the actual answer. Just you know what you have done. Others only can give the advice to lead you in the right way.